# Cannot get facebook video details using Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get video information (source URL, preview URL, title, description) using Facebook Graph API on Android. Everything work fine for friend's videos and some random public videos found on Facebook.

However, it doesn't work for videos uploaded using testing user accounts. These users are not in my friends list.

The HTTP query is:

> GET graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{video-id}

The API returns:

> {
>     "error": 
>     {
>       "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 
>       "type": "GraphMethodException", 
>       "code": 100
>      }
>     }

This happens both when using Facebook SDK for Android and Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).
This doesn't happen if I use APP Token instead of user access token.

If I use video owner's access token I can see video details but then requests fail for my own videos.

Every tested video is "public". I can watch these videos on Facebook without any problem.

Edit: following permissions are requested: "public_profile", "publish_actions", "user_videos", "user_birthday", "user_friends", "email", "user_location"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does *If I use video owner's access token I can see video details but then requests fail for my own videos.* mean? This kind of contradicts itself.

Comment: I control both user accounts. I mean if I log into the application using test account, the API works for that user videos and doesn't work for videos uploaded using my main account (and vice versa). Every video is public.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video#Reading

It states:

> - You must use a valid **Page Access Token or User Access Token** for any video with **public** privacy settings.
> - For **videos uploaded by someone**, and any videos in which they have been **tagged** you need a **user access token** for that person with **user_videos** permission.

Comment: I use valid User Access Token for API requests.  The access token includes "user_videos" permission.

Comment: Are you sure the Access Tokens are added to your requests?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The API returns different error ("An access token is required to request this resource.") if I remove access token from the request.

Comment: Is one account a "real" test user, or a normal profile user?